# How can I convert/compile a Python script into an e executable with no _Python_ dependencies?

Tags: python, build, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I've read this question:

[How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen)

and some (or all?) of the options there work. But - I don't care about removing *all* dependencies. I'm just fine with an executable which depends on glibc, libssl, libbz2 etc. - I just want it not to depend on anything Pythonic (mostly libpython3.something.so, and maybe Python-adjacent libs).

How can I achieve that? Specifically, can I use tools like pyinstaller, cypthon, nuitka etc. to achieve that?